# Serverless deploy seems to not access .env file

Tags: github, github-actions, serverless, serverless-framework

I want to deploy some serverless functions via GitHub Actions and the serverless framework.

However it seems that serverless can't access the `.env` file containing secrets and similar.

I always get this:

```
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
  - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.env.SCW_DEFAULT_REGION": Value not found at "env" source,
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
  - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.env.SCW_DEFAULT_PROJECT_ID": Value not found at "env" source,
  - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.secrets.SCW_ACCESS_KEY": Value not found at "env" source,
  - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.secrets.SCW_SECRET_KEY": Value not found at "env" source,
  - Cannot resolve variable at "functions.get-new-key.secret.GOOGLE_ADMIN_SDK_CREDS": Value not found at "env" source
```

I'v tried to use the stage keyword and and a serverless plugin from the the market place but doesn't work.

Here my workflow file:

```yaml
name: Deploy on PR
on:
    push:
        branches:
            - main
jobs: 
 build:
  environment:
    name: prod
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps: 
    - name: Checkout Code
      uses: actions/checkout@v4
    
    - name: Setup Go 1.20
      uses: actions/setup-go@v4
      with:
        go-version: '1.20'
        cache-dependency-path: |
             helper/go.sum
             scw_secret_wrapper/go.sum
             sign/go.sum
             cronjob/go.sum
             has_new_key/go.sum
             get_new_key/go.sum
      
    - name: Install all dependencies
      run: cd ${{github.workspace}}/scw_secret_wrapper && go get . && cd ${{github.workspace}}/helper && go get . && cd ${{github.workspace}}/sign && go get . && cd ${{github.workspace}}/cronjob && go get . && cd ${{github.workspace}}/has_new_key && go get . && cd ${{github.workspace}}/get_new_key && go get .

    - name: Run go mod vendor
      run: cd ${{github.workspace}}/get_new_key && go mod vendor && cd ${{github.workspace}}/has_new_key && go mod vendor && cd ${{github.workspace}}/sign && go mod vendor && cd ${{github.workspace}}/cronjob && go mod vendor

    - name: Convert secrets to .env file
      uses: shine1594/secrets-to-env-action@master
      with:
        secrets: ${{ toJSON(secrets) }}
        secrets_env: production
        file_name_prod: .env
    - name: Setup npm
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: '18'

    - name: Install serverless
      run: npm install -g serverless

    - name: Install serverless plugin
      run: serverless plugin install --name serverless-scaleway-functions
    
    - name: Deploy functins
      run: serverless deploy
```

serverless.yml file

```yaml
service: functions
configValidationMode: off
singleSource: false

useDotenv: true

provider:
  name: scaleway
  runtime: go120
  # stage: prod
  # region in which the deployment will happen (default: fr-par)
  scwRegion: nl-ams
  env:
    SCW_DEFAULT_REGION: ${env:SCW_DEFAULT_REGION}
    SCW_DEFAULT_PROJECT_ID: ${env:SCW_DEFAULT_PROJECT_ID}
    DEBUG: "false"

  secrets:
    SCW_ACCESS_KEY: ${env:SCW_ACCESS_KEY}
    SCW_SECRET_KEY: ${env:SCW_SECRET_KEY}

plugins:
  - serverless-scaleway-functions

package:
  patterns:
    - '!.gitignore'
    - '!.git/**'
    - '!*.sh'
    - 'node_modules/**'
    - '!.env'
    - '!tsconfig.json'
    - '!test/**'
    - '!debug-server'
    - '!build/debug-server'
    - '!build/test/**'
    - '!legacy/**'
    - '!go.work'
    - '!go.work.sum'
    - '!LICENSE'
    - '!README.md'
    - '!util'
    - 'cronjob/**'
    - '!tests/**'

functions:
  new-key-required:
    handler: has_new_key/HandleHasNewKey
    httpOption: redirected

  sign:
    handler: sign/HandleSignature
    httpOption: redirected

  get-new-key:
    handler: get_new_key/HandleGetNewKey
    httpOption: redirected
    secret:
      GOOGLE_ADMIN_SDK_CREDS: ${env:GOOGLE_ADMIN_SDK_CREDS}

  cron-job:
    handler: cronjob/Handle
    events:
      - schedule:
          # Every Sunday at 00:00 => https://crontab.guru/#0_0_*_*_0 | minute, hour, day (month) , month, day (week)
          rate: '0 0 * * 0'
```

Comment: Try mentioning appropriate permission in the workflow